# How to inject UTC timestamp into a hidden HTML form field from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I know next to nothing about Javascript.  I think I am almost there but need some help...

I need to pass UTC into a hidden field in an HTML form.  The actual time doesn't really matter, just using it as an order identifier that will be unique for each order.

Here is what I have but it isn't working...  Appreciate any help.

--- in form section ---

```
<input id="pg_consumerorderid" value="" type="hidden">
```

--- Script just below the < /form> tag

```
<script>
var field = document.querySelector('#pg_consumerorderid');
var date = Date.now();
// Set the date
field.value = date;
</script>
```

All my other form fields use input name= instead of the input id=  Not sure if that is messing things up.

Thanks!

Comment: put a name to the input

Comment: If I put a name to the input will I have to change this also?  If so, what do I change?  var field = document.querySelector('#pg_consumerorderid');

Comment: Nope you don't have to change, try it

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't work.  I just changed <input id="pg_consumerorderid" value="" type="hidden"> to <input name="pg_consumerorderid" value="" type="hidden">

Comment: you have to keep both name and id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kalhan.Toress](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2032751/kalhan-toress) said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65964664/how-to-inject-utc-timestamp-into-a-hidden-html-form-field-from-javascript/66038451#comment116630758_65964664) which gave the answer:

> you have to keep both name and id